# Facebook authentication in .NET with variable app ids in Startup.cs

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0

I am trying to have Facebook authentication in a .NET app. I have a method that needs to be called and sent parameters related to the Facebook app id. Basically, I want to use a different app id every time because I am creating multiple apps. The `useFacebookAuthentication` method must use the app id that is obtained here. I can't figure out how to do this because 'Startup' happens in the background.

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ....
        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
            appId: XXXX,
            appSecret: YYYY);
        ....
    }
```

I need to be able to vary XXXX and YYYY. How do I do this? I can't access the `Configuration(IAppBuilder app)` method myself; it's accessed in the background somewhere. I tried `View Call Hierarchy` and it found no results.

Comment: Can you use a web config variable?

Comment: @MarkC If I did that, how would I vary which web.config variable to use depending on how I call a Web Api method?